# java/spring printing out bean property values

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

does anybody have a simple way of printing out bean property values ? Without complicated instrospection constructs via getting propertyDescriptors etc. I'm talking about testing and checking that all properties have correct values, during development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PropertyDescriptors are the way to go, but Spring makes using them a lot easier if you use the [BeanWrapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapper.html) interface.

Here's a stupid test class:

```
public class Thingy{
    private final String foo = "hey";
    private final int bar = 123;
    private final List<String> grr = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");

    public String getFoo(){
        return this.foo;
    }
    public int getBar(){
        return this.bar;
    }
    public List<String> getGrr(){
        return this.grr;
    }
}
```

And here's a main method to inspect an instance of it:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception{
    final Thingy thingy = new Thingy();
    final BeanWrapper wrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(thingy);
    for(final PropertyDescriptor descriptor : wrapper.getPropertyDescriptors()){
        System.out.println(descriptor.getName() + ":"
            + descriptor.getReadMethod().invoke(thingy));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
bar:123
class:class com.mypackage.Thingy
foo:hey
grr:[1, 2, 3]
```

Read this for reference:

- [Bean manipulation and the BeanWrapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans)

Comment: I did it exactly as you said. This is the bean http://pastebin.com/242qAqHD . Only "progression" property wasn't set, otherwise the rest of bean properties was fully initialized with data. and the result is that "progression:  ", "movement:null", "startingPos:null" .... so that for movement and startingPos something went wrong...

Comment: @lisak that's strange. check this out: http://pastebin.com/Y7NmRdNi when I execute this, the properties are there

Answer (score 0):

[JSR-305: Annotations for Software Defect Detection](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/06/jsr-305-update)

Answer (score 0):

[BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) may be able to help you. postProcessBeforeInitialization() method will be called for each bean initialization and you can print values of properties there.

Post processor class:

```
public class ExampleBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof YourBean)
            System.out.println((YourBean) bean).getSomeProp());
        return bean;
    }
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Declare bean in bean file:

```
<bean class="ExampleBeanPostProcessor " />
```

Answer (score 0):

For a one liner can use the [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) library.

```
new Gson().toJson(myObject)
```

For maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope> <!-- remove you use gson in production -->
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add custom `<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">`

where

```
 @Override
    protected String resolvePlaceholder(String placeholder, Properties props) 

@Override
    protected String resolvePlaceholder(String placeholder, Properties props, int             systemPropertiesMode) 

    @Override
    protected String resolveSystemProperty(String key)
```